# Suffix-tree Detection of repeated string in sequences

Tags: string, algorithm, bioinformatics, suffix-tree

I have a collection of **k (k>2)** sequences. I need **an algorithm** that detects repeats (i.e. the appearance of the same string twice) in every sequence, where that repeated string is the same in all sequences. Also, I am wondering if there are any shortcomings if we try to put limitations in spaces between two string's appearances in every sequence. **Only suffix-tree solutions.**

Any tip will be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Example:

```
S1 = AATTAATTCGCG
S2 = GGAATTAATTCC
S3 = GAAATTAATTGA
Result= AATT
```

Comment: Why 'Only suffix-tree solutions'? Is this homework? (I would try to use a HashSet)

Comment: @MrSmith42 It is a task from Dan Gusfield book of Bioinformatics. I work on a bioinformatics project and I need practice. Unfortunately Dan Gusfield book does not offer solution manual.

Comment: I don't see `AATT` twice in `S3`? I'm not sure I understand the question, but probably you can solve it by constructing the suffix tree for `S1#S2$S3` and then computing a synthesized attribute bottom-up.